FirebaseAuth microsoft is not working on real devices
I am developing a flutter app which using Firebase Microsoft AD to login. My code looks like this:
OAuthProvider microsoftProvider = OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');
microsoftProvider.setCustomParameters({
    "tenant": "xxxxxxx",
  });
microsoftProvider.addScope('user.read');
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(microsoftProvider);

The login works fine on emulator, it will redirect the app to Google Chrome to proceed login. But the login is not working anymore on an APK built. Seems like there are some error on FirebaseAuth.
I've tried to run on multiple devices & emulator, unfortunately all devices also not working and all emulators is working smoothly. I also tried print error message on the app, but it returns null.
